# Bad fish configuration preventing usable login to remote server

Tags: ssh, shell, login, freebsd, fish

I messed up configuring my `config.fish`, and I now cannot use my server.

Whenever I try to log in, it says

```
fish: Unknown command '/usr/bin/keychain /home/freebsd/.ssh/id_dsa'
/home/freebsd/.config/fish/config.fish (line 21): /usr/bin/keychain $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa
```

It then just lets me type until I <strike>`^C`and end the connection</strike> close the terminal tab: the `^C` trick only happens sometimes.  Trying to `ssh root@server` just gives me the response to log in as the `freebsd` user.

If I try to `scp` to edit the remote `config.fish` to get rid of the offending lines, it still gives me the same error, rather than let me access the file.

Logging in to Digital Ocean and accessing the console is of absolutely no use whatsoever, since I have no idea what the passwords may be, since I always use `ssh` to log in (so there may only be the ssh keys, which I don't think I can use at the DO console prompt).

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/589547/log-in-with-different-shell-when-original-shell-is-broken) seems to indicate that I need to tell my VPS to do a hard reboot from DO's website and then do stuff with single user mode.  Is that the only way forward?

Answer (score 0):

`^D` got me to a prompt, so I could undo the changes to `config.fish`.

Comment: That suggests a command was running that was reading from stdin. Also, the fact you couldn't use `scp` suggests you're running things from your ~/.config/fish that are not appropriate for a non-interactive session. You probably need to guard some of your config.fish entries with `if status --interactive`.